# How to handle this fetch() TypeError?

Tags: javascript, typeerror, fetch-api

I am trying to print to the console (in order to later handle those edge cases) the response status of my fetch query. However, the only console.log call that works is the one in the 'breaches' function. I get no errors when an account exists in the HIBP db, but I get a 'Request failed: TypeError: response.json is not a function at json' error when the account is not in the db. What am I doing wrong? I got the error handling code from the [Google Web Dev](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/introduction-to-fetch) articles.

```
function createNode(element) {
    return document.createElement(element);
}

function append(parent, el) {
    return parent.appendChild(el);
}

function status(response) {
    if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
        return Promise.resolve(response)
        console.log('all is good');
    } else if (response.status == 404) {
        return Promise.resolve(response.statusText)
        console.log('no breaches');
    } else if (response.status == 400) {
        return Promise.resolve(response.statusText)
        console.log('bad req');
    } else {
        return Promise.reject(new Error(response.statusText))
    }
}

function json(response) {
    return response.json()
}

var account = document.getElementById('account'),
    results = document.getElementById('results');
account.addEventListener("keyup", keyupEvent);

function keyupEvent() {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.key === "Enter") {
        fetch('https://haveibeenpwned.com/api/v2/breachedaccount/' + account.value, {
                timeout: 1500,
                userAgent: 'test'
            })
            .then(status)
            .then(json)
            .then(function(breaches) {
                console.log('Status Code: ' + breaches.status);
                let span = createNode('span');
                return breaches.forEach(function(check) {
                    span.innerHTML = `${check.Name}<br/>`;
                    append(results, span)
                })

            }).catch(function(error) {
                console.log('Request failed:', error);
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: Side note: `if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {` => `if (response.ok)`

Comment: I guess the response status is 400 or 404

Comment: Your `console.log`s in `status` will never be executed, as they're **after** the `return` in each branch.

Comment: Also your `status` function has no need to create new promises, just have it directly (and synchronously) return the desired result, or `throw` for the final `else` clause.    Creating additional promises like this is a common promise anti-pattern.

Comment: Does `haveibeenpwned.com` **really** return a status = 404 page if there are no breaches? I know it's a matter of debate, but I find the conflation of application-layer logic with HTTP logic...unfortunate. And the complication above is why: Do you parse the response text on 404 or not? Is it a 404 with valid JSON saying "no breaches," or a 404 with an HTML page saying you've requested an invalid URI?

Comment: Finally, your `fetch` chain seems to expect that `breaches` at the end will be an array (`breaches.forEach`...) but with a `status` property. JavaScript's arrays can be that way, but JSON doesn't provide for arrays like that, so you're not going to get one as the result of `response.json()`.

Comment: Thanks, @T.J.Crowder and Alnitak. I don't really understand Promises - I've read an article about them - so I don't really know how to use them. As for the return fiasco, yeah, that was... embarassing :)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, regarding you 404 statement - the latter: https://imgur.com/a/a6GWemq

Comment: I want to detect the response so I can append to the <div> a text letting him know that his account wasn't breached.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `status` function returns (a promise of) the status **text** for responses that are 400s or 404s. Your promise chain consuming the `fetch` result doesn't handle that possibility; it assumes it gets the response object.

You probably want to reject on 400s or 404s rather than resolving, but if not, you'll need to branch in your `then` handler expecting to read JSON.

Your code consuming the breaches is also overwriting the same `span` and repeatedly appending it; it will end up appended only once, with the *last* breach's information. And the `append` function doesn't provide any useful abstraction over just calling `appendChild`.

If the API really returns 404 for "no breaches" (blech), then I'd get rid of `createNode` and `append`, change `status` to this:

```
function status(response) {
    if (response.ok) {
        return response.json();
    } else if (response.status === 404) { // If the API *really* returns
        return [];                        // a 404 for "no breaches"
    } else {
        throw new Error(response.statusText);
    }
}
```

and then:

```
fetch('https://haveibeenpwned.com/api/v2/breachedaccount/' + account.value, {
        timeout: 1500,
        userAgent: 'test'
    })
    .then(status)
    .then(breaches => {
        // No `return` here, the chain isn't passed on and there
        // aren't any further resolution handlers
        breaches.forEach(check => {  // Or a for-of loop
            const span = document.createElement("span");
            span.innerHTML = `${check.Name}<br/>`;
            results.appendChild(span);
        });
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log('Request failed:', error);
    });
```

---

Separately: Your `status` function suggests that you don't realize that `then` (and `catch`) *create new promises*. There's no reason for your `status` function to create any promises if it's only going to be used as a `then` handler. It should just a return a value (the promise created by `then` will resolve with that value) or throw an error (the promise created by `then` will reject with that error):

```
// This is equivalent to your current `status` function (assuming it's always
// used as a `then` callback)
function status(response) {
    if (response.ok) { // if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
        // all okay
        return response;
    } else if (response.status == 404) {
        // no breaches
        return response.statusText;
    } else if (response.status == 400) {
        // bad request
        return response.statusText;
    } else {
        throw new Error(response.statusText);
    }
}
```

*(I removed the `console.log` lines that were* after *the `return` in each branch, as they were unreachable.)*

Comment: Sidenote: where did you learn about the fetch() API? I'm new to it so I had a bit of a tough time reading your explanation. I did it like this: https://jsfiddle.net/flaregun/bnmd40ag/ and I still get a 'Request failed: TypeError: response.json is not a function' error.

Comment: @MadameTuxstdout - MDN is a great resource for this stuff: [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalFetch/fetch) (also for [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/javascript), [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model), and [CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS) information).